# error: TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to replace a substring by another one using this code:

```
var body = 'Message: ' + req.query.message.replace('/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g', '<br/>');
```

But, proceeding that way I get this error message on that line:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined
```

I wasn't able to find the solution to fix this using javascript. What I've found is related to only jQuery.

Any brilliant idea how to fix that, please?

Comment: The value of `req.query.message` is not a string, it is `undefined`. You have to find out why it's not a string before you can replace anything in the string.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's saying req.query.message is undefined. You have to figure out why that is undefined.